# Android Dialog setContentView not executing the layout's context java file

Tags: java, android

Seems quite simple. Dialog inflates the activity_hint layout file. That layout file has HintActivity.java as context. HintActivity.java is never executing. I've made some careless error?

**MainActivity:**

```
public void onHintClick(View view) {
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_hint);
    dialog.show();
}
```

**activity_hint.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/hint_bg"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".HintActivity">
```

**HintActivity.java** (this file is never executed. Log never appears. If I set onClickListeners to buttons, they do not work.)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("hintss", "hints");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Dialog` is **not** an activity. 
When you inflate a layout for the dialog this does not mean that the activity class mentioned inside the layout by this attribute:

```
tools:context=".HintActivity"
```

will start to execute its code.  
The above attribute is not even compiled and is used only for design purposes.  
You can use the inflated layout views by `findViewById`, like:

```
Button button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.somebutton)
```

but all the code must be written in `onHintClick()`